# How to draw a rectangle perpendicular to a line, or to the tangent of a curve, in JavaScript Canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, trigonometry

I have a series of lines, curves, and arcs drown randomly on a HTML5 canvas.
There's a rectangle at the left of the line, and the line slides to the left and moves on the y axis in a way that it always passes throw the middle of the rectangle. The problem is that I would like the middle of the right side of the rectangle to be always perpendicular to the line, even when the line curves.
[perpendicular rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfsDZ.png)

How can I achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: Store the points of the line and calculate the slope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need calculate the angle of line and set this in rect. Look the review solution in my project:

```js
  delta_x = x2 - x1;
  delta_y = y2 - y1;
  angle = Math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x);
```

https://codepen.io/Luis4raujo/pen/gOLRqzq?editors=1111

Now, you need adjusting x and y position of rect.

Comment: Maybe u get the correct x and y if considerate the base of rect is the center. In summary: change a centre of the rect to your bottom limit.